# How can I create a calculated column based off a different table in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two hypothetical tables in PowerBI. The first one, called `Query1`, has various sale transaction numbers, many of them happening on similar dates (also included). So, we have two pertinent in `Query1`, and they are `'Query1'[transaction_number]` and `'Query1'[transaction_date]`.

Now, suppose I'd like to create another table, called `Query2`. The first column is set to `'Query1'[transaction_date]`. The second column should be the count of transaction numbers associated with that date, with the underlying information taken from `Query1`.

I've tried the following:

`transaction_count = COUNT('Query1'[transaction_number])` but unfortunately, all I got was a column of the total number of transaction numbers *regardless* of transaction date. I'd like a column with the count of each transaction per that specific day.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it be enough to use the "group by" command?

Comment: The GROUPBY function is similar to the SUMMARIZE function. However, GROUPBY does not do an implicit CALCULATE for any extension columns that it adds. Bottom line - SUMMARIZE / SUMMARIZECOLUMNS is better.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use 
[SUMMARIZECOLUMNS Function (DAX)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163696.aspx).

```
Query2 =
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    'Query1'[transaction_date],
    "transaction_count ", SUMX ( 'Query1', 'Query1'[transaction_number] )
)
```

In my understanding you will need SUMX inside SUMMARIZECOLUMNS however if you really need to count number of rows just replace `SUMX` with `COUNTX` 
[COUNTX Function (DAX)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634549.aspx).